# How to add multiple fields for sorting top hits in ElasticSearch Java API?

Tags: elasticsearch

I know that ES supports sorting top hits by more than one fields, like `sort: ["_score", "datetime"]` suggested by this post: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/top-hits-query-with-same-score/107018

But how to do it using Java API?

The `AggregationBuilders.topHits().sort()` only receives one field as parameter.

Should I use
[image]
and [SortBuilder](https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/7.9.3/org/elasticsearch/search/sort/SortBuilder.html) as parameter?

If so, `SortBuilder` asks for a [QueryShardContext](https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/7.9.3/org/elasticsearch/index/query/QueryShardContext.html) parameter, which I don't know how to create. I have never used it before. None of the other requests uses this `QueryShardContext`.

Is there any simple way to do it, like, just pass in an array of fields into `sort()`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [overloaded `TopHitsAggregationBuilder.sort()` methods](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/metrics/TopHitsAggregationBuilder.java#L222-L275), namely one that takes `String name`, i.e. the name of a field, so you can do it like this:

```
TopHitsAggregationBuilder thabuilder = AggregationBuilders.topHits("top");
thabuilder.sort("datetime", SortOrder.DESC);
thabuilder.sort("field2", SortOrder.ASC);
...
```

All the sort calls will add a new sort component to the top-hits aggregation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So in your example, `thabuilder.sort("datetime", SortOrder.DESC);` will take effect before `thabuilder.sort("field2", SortOrder.ASC);`, is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's right, you can set the order as you see fit